# Can't delete selected indexes from list with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am faced with a big challenge to delete selected indexes from a list I have tried splice and Vuejs delete() function yet i can't get it working.

this is an example snippet of what i am trying to achieve.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",
    data:{
        list:[
            {name:'emi1',dob:'100583'},
            {name:'emi2',dob:'100584'},
            {name:'emi3',dob:'100585'},
            {name:'emi4',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi5',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi6',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi7',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi8',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi9',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi10',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi11',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi12',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi13',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi14',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi15',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi16',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi17',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi18',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi19',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi20',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi21',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi22',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi23',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi24',dob:'100586'},
            {name:'emi25',dob:'100586'}
        ],
        indexes:[0,3,5,7,10,15]
    },
    methods:{
        deleteSelected(){
            this.indexes.forEach((n,i)=>{
                this.$delete(this.list[n],n);
            }); 
        }
    }
    ,
    computed:{
        listrender:function(){
            return this.list;
        }
    }
});
```

When i echo the list it shows the said deleted items still remains.

Please I need help.

Comment: Why are you relying on index number for the array? If the data is changing, that's not a good thing to rely on. For large lists without unique ids, I generate a unique hash and use that as the :key in v-for and also an use it to delete or filter out specific items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try in this way:

```
for (var i = this.indexes.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {

   this.list.splice(this.indexes[i],1);

}
```

This because deleting an item inside a loop will cause indexes of other items to change. So you need to delete them starting from the end.

Answer (score 2):

`vm.delete()` takes the arguments:

1. Object or Array
2. Key if object or index if array

But you are passing nth item of an array as 1st argument.

```
this.$delete(this.list[n],n);
```

So change it to

```
this.$delete(this.list,n);
```

Here is the [partly working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5yr2j43/3/)

## But

There is a small bug. If you see the items you will find out that the items that are getting deleted are not the items you want to delete.

For example consider the first two indexes i.e `0, 3`

So the items that need to be deleted are `{name:'emi1',dob:'100583'}` and `{name:'emi4',dob:'100586'}`

But `{name:'emi5',dob:'100586'}` is getting deleted instead of `{name:'emi4',dob:'100586'}`

This is happening because for each loop iteration the list is being modified and nth item is being removed from the newly modified list.

To overcome this problem loop the `this.indexes` list backwards and delete each item

```
deleteSelected() {
  for (let i = this.indexes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    this.$delete(this.list, this.indexes[i]);
  }
}
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n872psja/1/)

## Note

For this to  work the indexes inside `this.indexes` must be in ascending order. If not use `Array.prototype.sort()` to sort the indexes in ascending order

Answer (score 1):

```
deleteSelected(){
    let newlist = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<this.list.length; i++) {
        if(this.indexes.includes(i)) {continue;}
        newlist.push(this.list[i]);
        }
    this.list = newlist;
    }
```